# Replace JSON response value ID by the object. [CakePHP 3]

Tags: json, rest, api, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Sorry, if the title sounds confusing, I tried my best.

Right now I have this :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id_reservation": 101,
    "id_venue": 2,
    "id_user": 67
  }
}
```

When GETing a reservation from my API, what I'm looking for is

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id_reservation": 101,
    "venue": {
     "id_venue": 2,
     "venue_name": "TEST",
     "location": "TEST",
     "venue_type": "TEST"
     },
     "id_user": 67
  }
}
```

I want to have the object using the ID in my JSON response, how could I achieve this with CakePHP 3?

Comment: By actually including it via your find query? Your question is extremely vague, some hints regarding the actual technical problem that you are facing wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're getting the Venue Models with a \Cake\ORM\Query or the object VenuesTable.

You also need to load the associations' Reservation and User, you should read this documentation: [Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)

You have to use the contain method like this :

```
$venueEntity = $this->Venues
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Reservations',
        'Users',
    ])
    // then your conditions
    ->where(['venue_id' => $venueId])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Venue" looks like a related table. So you need to make a find requesting all related models. To ensure receiving what you want make a join in the find and set in the "fields" those you want.